# Difference between Twitter intent & Twitter share URLs

Tags: twitter

I've been having some character encoding problems with twitter's text query string parameter.

a) [http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://www.example.com&text=touché](http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://www.example.com&text=touch%C3%A9)

b) [http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.example.com&text=touché](http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.example.com&text=touch%C3%A9)

a) seems to do extra encoding and the tweet comes out wrong

b) see lack of www works fine.

These both redirect to :
    [http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=touch%C3%A9&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com](http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=touch%C3%A9&url=http://www.example.com)

Is there a point in using http://twitter.com/share rather than simply just: http://twitter.com/intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more information about the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1915) and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4205). Use [web intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents) without the `www`.

Twitter was double encoding characters in certain situations. Adding a `www` to the sharer url was one of those bugs. It was also happening with some of the [other features](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2005) as well.